# PHP offset date() result based on user's timezone?

Tags: php, date, timezone

I am storing when events happened on my site in the database using the `time()` function and echoing them out with the `date()` function.

My only problem is that it echoes it out as UTC but what if my users are elsewhere in the world? How would I detect their timezone and pass it out to the `date()` function?

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use `mysql` - you could use `timestamp` column and mysql will do the left for you. Also - for formatting and arithmetic purposes you could use `DateTime` php class instead of plain old `date()`

Comment: @zerkms That is an inefficient way of doing this.

Comment: im confused... i dont know how to convert timestamp into readable time and what is DateTime in php? also I would prefer not to change my database too much as it is already being closed beta tested.

Comment: @Vulcan: uhm, I'm sorry? Any explanations?

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone

Comment: @Vulcan, how is it a duplicate? I didnt find that nor did I create that

Comment: @Vulcan, if possible, I dont want to use JS because I want to include it in a file known as "settings.php" and i want to be able to edit headers afterward

Comment: My bad, not so much a duplicate as a referral.  You don't need to use JS.  Notice that the accepted answer has 46 upvotes for 38 downvotes.  Check out the other answers.

Comment: @Vulcan: would you explain what's wrong with my comment?

Comment: @Vulcan can you help me a bit with understanding how I would use "JD Isaacks" answer as it seems the most practical, so would I just set it as a variable and then subtract that from time() and then pass it into a date() function?

Comment: @MuqMan "JD Isaacks"'s answer uses JS. zerkms, At a second look, how would your proposed solution even work? MySQL does not know the user's time offset.

Comment: @Vulcan so is it possible with PHP? Because I need the headers editable after the timezone detect

Comment: It's easy to manipulate the result of `date`, but the point is, you need to use _users'_ timezone, which is beyond PHP's range. I think a practical solution would be JS. Send your UTC time to client, and use JS on clients' side to convert them to whatever timezone.

Comment: @MuqMan PHP is server-side, so no.  You either will need to use a client-side language such as JS, or ask your users to choose their timezone and then store it in a cookie.

Comment: could this be done when the user logs in? and then set as a session variable without disrupting the header? @Passerby, can I please see the "BEST" javascript? Please put it in an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Vulcan ok as I said before, can this be done when the user logs in and then stored as a session variable without disrupting the header?

Comment: @MuqMan Look at the question I linked earlier in these comments; it contains JS answers.  The accepted answer provides low-quality JS, so I recommend looking at others.

Comment: @Vulcan but how would I get the JS to interact with the PHP as I store user session info in a table? it wouldnt work exactly would it?

Comment: @MuqMan I don't understand what exactly you're asking, but you shouldn't need to store timezone with user session info.

Comment: @Vulcan: my comment was addressed to the second question part. When you already know user's timezone and need to perform some TZ arithmetics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if you prefer the session way, place a hidden field in user login form, and use JS to give it a value. Simple illustration:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="hidden" name="offset" id="offset">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
document.getElementById("offset").value=(new Date).getTimezoneOffset();
</script>
```

And on PHP side, manipulate the result of `date` like this:

```
$_SESSION["offset"]=intval($_GET["offset"]);
/*works here...*/
$date=date("Y-m-d",time()-($_SESSION["offset"]*60));
```

And if you want to do it all clients way, also use `Date().getTimezoneOffset()` to manipulate the result.

[MDN Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: wait, can I not simply post it in an input type=hidden and just make it - or + UTC?

Comment: @MuqMan What do you mean? This method is just POSTing "-240" (in minute).

Comment: @MuqMan `$_POST["offset"]` would be good enough...I also edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Tue Aug 21 2012 23:47:22 GMT-0400 (EDT) is what it prints when I document.write it? is this right?

Comment: @MuqMan No...`(new Date).getTimezoneOffset()` should return something like `-480` for GMT +8 (which seems a little weird to me).

Comment: oh I messed up the document.write syntax

Comment: it turns out you just add a - to the result

Comment: @MuqMan I did this in IE6(!) and Chrome console, they all return negative result for a positive GMT timezone, that's why I use minus in PHP side. Anyway, you should be able to get the idea on how to implement it in your project.

Comment: hey um, how would I set my default timezone to UTC in my config so I can work from there?

Comment: @MuqMan You can use PHP's configuration [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)